# Inject json object to html element

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I made an html page the has the following code and what I want to do is map a `json` element to the value of data-site-key to equal the object site-key instead of "`6LeoeSkTAAAAAA9rkZs5oS82l69OEYjKRZAiKdaF`".

**config.json**

```
{
  "sitekey": "6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7KpuC9AV-6J8mhw4AjC3Xz",
  "bankPort": "8080"
}
```

HTML

```html
     <html>
    <head>
     <title>Captcha Harvester</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    
    
    <body>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </body>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <form action="/submit" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" id="captchaFrame" data-sitekey="6LeoeSkTAAAAAA9rkZs5oS82l69OEYjKRZAiKdaF" data-callback="sub"></div>
     </form>
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
     <script>
    
      const remote = require('electron').remote
        const app = remote.app
        const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer
    
      function sub() {
       ipcRenderer.send('sendCaptcha', grecaptcha.getResponse());
       grecaptcha.reset();
      }
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Stringify your json config and you can set the result to your `data-siteke` attribut

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

[image]

```js
const siteKey = 
{
  sitekey: "6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7KpuC9AV-6J8mhw4AjC3Xz",
  bankPort: "8080"
}

const siteKeyString = JSON.stringify(siteKey)

const div = document.getElementById("divTest")

div.dataset.sitekey = siteKeyString

console.log(div)
```

```html
<div id="divTest" data-sitekey ="">Inspect Me!</div>
```

Comment: yes basically but I need the site key in a separate file.

Comment: Once you set it the value, you can get it with `JSON.parse(div.dataset.sitekey)` in any script attached to the page.

Comment: oh wait... is that for 2 files?

Comment: I think you are a litte bit confused. if you put this for example:
`<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
`
Every function that you have in script1.js will be able in script2.js.
And both scripts will be able to access to the DOM.

Comment: document is not defined?

Comment: Read it: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: yea but if your calling document in a js file there is no body? right? does `const siteKeyString = JSON.stringify(siteKey)

const div = document.getElementById("divTest")

div.dataset.sitekey = siteKeyString

console.log(div)` go on the html page?

Comment: Add me to Discord: Arklight#1928